# Decoding extrinsic hex into readable form in Rust

Tags: rust, extrinsic, subxt, decode

I am running the substrate-dev node. Made a transaction using Polkadot-explorer. After fetching the block using subxt I am getting extrinsic hex as:

```
8400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d016a0d5d23b65049765a0141666edf0108dc326ced62c96a3092a74471c3bd00382aa84dfd9b12ce199560a26ac6126e1f5f50a59bd50c798f408979843153908c66071000000008081234
```

I want to convert this hex into a readable form in Rust.

Comment: Just to say, Subxt doesn't currently support decoding blocks into anything useful, but it's next up on the roadmap and should be out by the end of Jan 2023, all being well!

Answer (score 1):

You need to confirm the `Type` first.

Then:

```rs
use parity_scale_codec::Decode;

#[derive(Debug, Decode)]
struct MockExtrinsicType { .. }

let extrinsic = MockExtrinsicType::decode(&mut &*array_bytes::hex2bytes_unchecked("8400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d016a0d5d23b65049765a0141666edf0108dc326ced62c96a3092a74471c3bd00382aa84dfd9b12ce199560a26ac6126e1f5f50a59bd50c798f408979843153908c66071000000008081234"));
println!("{:?}", extrinsic);
```

Usually, the block type is https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f2bc08a3071a91b71fec63cf2b22c707411cec0e/primitives/runtime/src/generic/block.rs#L92.

And the extrinsic type is https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f2bc08a3071a91b71fec63cf2b22c707411cec0e/primitives/runtime/src/lib.rs#L868.

Finally, you need to decode the `OpaqueExtrinsic` into this https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f2bc08a3071a91b71fec63cf2b22c707411cec0e/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L44.

Comment: thanks, what are the possible types? and how can I confirm them.

Comment: Where did you get this result? Need more detail to analyze this.

Comment: i got it from running an extrinsic from polkadot-ui.
`Developers -> Extrinsics -> System -> remarkWithEvent -> Value:0x1234`
and then running 
`let block = client.rpc().block(Some(block_hash)).await?; `
using subxt providing the blockhash of event
and then 
`block.block.extrincics[1]` returns me this hex

Comment: @AurevoirXavier but how to decode the OpaqueExtrinsic into unchecked_extrinsic ?